# Why isn't the RHS of the Geodesic Equation equal to 1?

Tags: differential-geometry

The classic version of the Geodesic Equation states:$$\frac{d u^{\alpha }}{d \tau }+u^{\mu } u^{\nu } \Gamma_{\mu  \nu }^{\alpha }=0$$

I proposed that it should be:
$$\frac{d u^{\alpha }}{d \tau }+u^{\mu } u^{\nu } \Gamma_{\mu  \nu }^{\alpha }=a_3^{\alpha }$$
Where $\boldsymbol{a_3}$ is the ubiquitous acceleration tensor field of the manifold. Could be zero, could be something else. It depends on what kind of manifold you have. In one the comments that followed, it was observed that I could simply take the acceleration term, $\boldsymbol{a_3}$, move it to the LHS, and then integrate it with the Christoffel Symbols to make it agree with the classic equation. This is true, but it got me to thinking, why can't I use the exact same logic in reverse, and say:
$$\frac{d u^{\alpha }}{d \tau }+u^{\mu } u^{\nu } \Gamma_{\mu  \nu }^{\alpha }=1$$I can always hide a constant of 1 in the Christoffel Symbols. What is special about zero in the classic Geodesic Equation (I mean, other than the fact that it allows you to imagine a manifold in terms of comfortable Minkowski space)?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143046/discussion-on-question-by-quark-soup-why-isnt-the-rhs-of-the-geodesic-equation); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 11):

You’ve asked about 5 questions about the geodesic equation, all along the same lines so let me make the following remarks. The geodesic equation (on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ equipped with the Levi-Civita connection) is **by definition** the name given to the following equation:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=0.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Other names include the autoparallel equation, or the affine geodesic equation (reserving ‘geodesic equation’ for $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=f\dot{\gamma}$ for some function $f$; but this has to do with choice of parameters, so let us just stick to the above equation). Now, I don’t know why you’re trying so hard to call something that is not the geodesic equation a geodesic equation. It’s like if I had a pet goldfish and I started calling it a cat instead.

Now, if you wanted to, you could definitely consider the following situation: a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, a vector field $A$ defined on $M$, and ask for curves $\gamma:I\to M$ which satisfy the equation
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}&=A\circ \gamma.\tag{$**$}
\end{align}
We no longer call this the geodesic equation. Also, for this equation, one needs the additional piece of information regarding $A$. The question of whether $A$ is zero or not has nothing to do with the curvature or topology of $M$.

Equation $(*)$ is the starting point of everything because in the Riemannian case, curves which satisfy that equation are precisely the ones which are locally length-minimizing (so they’re the ‘shortest’ curves) and in general they’re the ones which are ‘straightest’ in the sense of the parallel transport of tangent vectors being themselves. These are the properties of straight lines that we know and love from Euclidean geometry, so we have decided to abstract that idea, and that’s why we give $(*)$ the name ‘geodesic equation’.

So, putting an $A$ on the RHS gives you a completely different equation (and again, $A$ being zero or non-zero has nothing to do with the curvature of $M$, it is an additional **choice** that you have to make); you’re definitely allowed to study that equation, but just don’t mix things up. Solutions to this equation (with non zero $A$) do not locally minimize length and are not ‘straight’ in the above sense of being their own parallel-transport. Now, if your actual concern is whether or not people actually study things like equation $(**)$ in practice, then the answer is yes, it appears all over the place. Physically, one might interpret it as ‘Newton’s second law’ (though usually it is written as $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=-\text{grad}_g(V)\circ\gamma$, since we consider force fields which come from some potential).

Comment: *"We no longer call this the geodesic equation"* Please tell me what you call it and I'll be more than happy to use the term in my next question.

Comment: @QuarkSoup I call it Newton’s second law when appropriate, or I might (but don’t) call it an inhomogeneous geodesic equation, or I literally just write down the equation, because there’s no ambiguity once I write down the equation. But again, whether or not you have an $A$ that is zero or not, makes literally zero difference when it comes to the length of a curve. Lengths of curves are determined **COMPLETELY** by the metric tensor field $g$.

Comment: Just to add to the last comment a bit, in the context of the other comment chain above, you WANT this to be the case. If your spacetime has some field on it that exerts a force, you want the difference between the path particles actually take and the geodesic to be something you can talk about. Calling the paths things take under a force "geodesic" is confusing, because it's exactly the deviation from a geodesic that allows you to measure the force being exerted.

Comment: ^exactly, and while we’re briefly talking Physics, Einstein wanted (due to the (weak) equivalence principle ‘gravitational mass=inertial mass’, a ‘fact’ which was known since Galileo’s time, and wanting to combine this with special relativity) to encode gravitational effects not as forces, but as an intrinsic part of motion of free particles. Hence, we now have the saying ‘gravity is not a force’, and we talk about the geodesic equation in a $3+1$ dimensional Lorentzian manifold (the impossibility of doing this in 3D is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/643925/203278)).

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're doing here. No, force is an assumption you brought to the conversation. I'm saying "forget physics, what's to stop a manifold from having a non-zero acceleration tensor (vector) field?" If you could explain that, then I think I'd understand (*) better.

Comment: I still don't know what an acceleration tensor field is. I know what a tensor field is. You equip $M$ with a tensor field. So what? How does this field have anything to do with geodesics?

Comment: @QuarkSoup I wrote my Einstein comment purely as that: a comment, so feel free to ignore that. My main answer is already written above, where I clearly stated in the second paragraph “Now, if you wanted to, you could definitely consider the following situation…” and in the last paragraph I again reiterate that you have all the freedom in the world to consider a non-zero $A$. Literally no one is stopping you. But, if you do consider non-zero $A$, then those curves no longer locally minimize lengths, they are no longer their own parallel-transports. So they’re not short or straight in any sense.

Comment: you should read my answer more carefully. Honestly, I’m not making any deep points here (some might say I’m even making almost tautological points), so it seems to me you need to brush up on differential geometry to understand what is vs isn’t being said.